# How to validate subforms of an entity-mapped form in Symfony2?

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.0

I've got a form that is mapped to an entity (`'data_class' => ...`). I've got validators set up (via annotations) on the entity's properties.

The entity has a property (`nameTranslations`) of doctrine's type `array`. I created a custom field type composed of multiple fields that is assigned to this field in the form. Each of the subform's fields (of type `text`) has validators setup (`NotBlank`) via `validation_constraint` option.

I tried various validation annotations on the `nameTranslations` property, including `Valid()`. I tried settings error_bubbling on almost anything. The subform (field `nameTranslations`) doesn't get validated at all.

The subform:

```php
class TranslatableTextType extends AbstractType
{
    private $langs;

    /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
    public function __construct($multilang)
    {
        $this->langs = $multilang->getLangs();
    }

    /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        foreach($this->langs as $locale => $lang)
        {
            $builder->add($locale, 'text', array(
                'label' => sprintf("%s [%s]", $options['label'], $lang),
                'error_bubbling' => true,
            ));
        }
    }

    /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        $constraints = [
            'fields' => [],
            'allowExtraFields' => true,
            'allowMissingFields' => true,
        ];

        foreach($this->langs as $locale => $lang)
        {
            $constraints['fields'][$locale] = new NotBlank();
        }

        $collectionConstraint = new Collection($constraints);

        return [
            'validation_constraint' => $collectionConstraint,
            'label' => '',
            'error_bubbling' => true
        ];
    }

    /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
    public function getParent(array $options)
    {
        return 'form';
    }

    /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'translatable_text';
    }
}
```

In the main form:

```php
$builder->add('nameTranslations', 'translatable_text', [
            'label' => 'Name'
        ]);
```

In the entity:

```php
/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @Assert\Valid
 * @ORM\Column(type="array")
 */
protected $nameTranslations;
```

Comment: This problem was fixed in further symfony versions. I think this was a bug in 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [collection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) type for that instead of custom one or your custom type should have collection type defined as parent.

You can use [All](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/All.html) validator like:

```
/**
 * @Assert\All({
 *     @Assert\NotBlank
 * })
 * @ORM\Column(type="array")
 */
 protected $nameTranslations;
```

it will check if each of array value is not blank.

Comment: It is not well suited for a collection, there is a (for the most part of time) fixed number of fields. Besides I've got exactly the same problem with another field - which couldn't be converted to collection even if I wanted to. I do not understand why symfony doesn't validate the subform when it's every field has a validator and the field that this subform is attached to also has validator (`ORM\Validate`). Even if your solution worked (can't test it right now, back at home) it would validate the subform as a whole - it would be nicer if every field was treated separately (UX).

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/form.html#cascade-validation that why it is not validate subforms by default... and I do not understand why fixed number of fields not suite for collection type... collection type should be use when you want have many subforms (types)... BTW even if you not use collection you can validate that by All constraint

Comment: From `cascade_validation`:
_Instead of using this option, you can also use the Valid constraint in your model to force validation on a child object stored on a property._

Already tried the `Valid` contraint.

As far as the collection dispute is concerned - I can't use collection for the other field with the same problem. Collection isn't suitable for many fields and it feels more like workaround rather than solution.